# Text Cursor Handle stays Blue

Tags: dart, flutter

I tried `cursorColor` and wrapping the `TextField` in a `Theme` where `textSelectionHandleColor` and `textSelectionColor` are set to whatever colors, however, the *text cursor **stays blue***.

[image]
[image]

To be clear, I am talking about *the handle*. None of the following adjust it for me:

- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14598
- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15571

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, it is currently [not possible](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20219#issuecomment-415760402) to change the `textSelectionHandleColor` of a `TextField` by modifying its parent `Theme`. The only `Theme` that changes the `textSelectionHandleColor` is the `Theme` directly inside the `MaterialApp` ([source](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20219#issuecomment-415760402)).

Issue on GitHub: [textSelectionHandleColor is not working/changing. #20219](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20219)

The reason this problem exists is that the handles are rendered inside an [Overlay](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Overlay-class.html). The `Overlay` is not a child from the `TextField`, but instead always a child of the `MaterialApp`. Here is a failed try from another developer to solve the problem: [textSelectionHandleColor taken from parent's context. Fixes #20219](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/22026)

---

Therefore you can currently only adjust the `MaterialApp` inside your application:

[image: Demo]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: Theme.of(context).copyWith(textSelectionHandleColor: Colors.red),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: TextField(
            autofocus: true,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I just checked the tickets, 1 year and still no fix. (I have the same issue)